# Jquery how can I findout if I have a checked checkbox then put it into a if statement

Tags: jquery

I am new to Jquery I have the following code below that will check if any checkboxes are checked  . What I would like to do is get the result of that then (checked / not checked) put it in an if statement ( get a true or false or checked/not checked and put it in a variable so that then I can use an if statement

```
$("#treeview .k-item input[type=checkbox]:checked").closest(".k-item");
```

For example I would like to do something like below

```
var isChecked = $("#treeview .k-item input[type=checkbox]:checked").closest(".k-item");

if (isChecked == true)
   {
     // I know it's true do something
    } else {
         // It's false do something else
         }
```

Comment: Can you post your HTML code too?

Comment: `var isChecked = $("#treeview .k-item input[type=checkbox]:checked").length > 0`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample example.

I am expecting your HTML as below

```
<div id="treeview">
    <div class="k-item">
        <input type="checkbox" /> <label>ZZZ</label>
        <input type="checkbox" /> <label>VVV</label>
        <input type="checkbox" /> <label>CCC</label>
        <input type="checkbox" /> <label>XXX</label>
        <input type="checkbox" /> <label>DDD</label>
    </div>
    <input type="button" id="btnSubmit" value="Check" />
</div>
```

Below is the script you could use.

```
$("#btnSubmit").on("click", function(){
    var isChecked = $("#treeview .k-item input[type=checkbox]").is(":checked");
    if(isChecked){
        alert("checked");
    }
    else{
        alert("none checked");
    }
});
```

Here is a [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/qyfchx0s/)

Answer (score 0):

to check if checkbox is checked or not, you can do

```
if( $('#specific_checkbox').is(':checked') ){
//  its checked, do something

}else{

}
```

or

```
if( $('#specific_checkbox:checked').length > 0 ){
// checked
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This Demo will:

- collect all checkboxes with the jQuery selector extension **[`:checkbox`](https://api.jquery.com/checkbox-selector/)**.
- record each checkbox's id and if the checkbox is checked value will be recorded and stored in the **[Map Object](https://medium.com/front-end-hacking/es6-map-vs-object-what-and-when-b80621932373)**.
- all unchecked checkboxes values are recorded in the Map Object as null.
- On change event, each checkbox will be wrapped in a label.
- Each checkbox label will display the checkbox's id to the left and value to the right. This is done by CSS function **[`attr()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/attr)**

---

### Demo

**Details commented in Demo**

```js
/* Register all checkboxes to the change event
|| Invoke the checkCheckbox() callback function
|| and pass its return value through to displayMap() function
*/
$(':checkbox').on('change', function() {

  // Create an ES6 Map
  var map = new Map();
  var m = checkCheckbox(map);
  displayMap(m);
});

// Pass the Map through
function checkCheckbox(map) {

  // On each checkbox...
  $(':checkbox').each(function(idx) {

    //...store the total number of checkboxes...
    var qty = $(':checkbox').length;

    //...store the last index number created...
    var num = idx + qty;

    // if this checkbox doesn't have an id...
    if (!$(this).attr('id')) {

      //...then assign an id to it and...
      $(this).attr('id', `chx${num}`);

      //...create a string of a label...
      var str = $(`<label for="${this.id}"><b data-val="${this.value}"></b></label>`);

      /*...insert label string after checkbox then 
      || insert the checkbox as the first child of label
      */
      $(this).after(str);
      str.prepend($(this));
    }
    // if this checkbox is checked...
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {

      //...get its value...
      var val = $(this).val();

      //...set its value within the Map...
      map.set(this.id, val);

      // ...otherwise...
    } else {

      //...set its value to Map as null
      map.set(this.id, null);
    }
  });
  return map;
}


// Utility function that displays a Map to console
function displayMap(map) {
  for (let [key, value] of map) {
    console.log(key + '=' + value);
  }
}
```

```css
label {
  border: 3px outset grey;
  border-radius: 5px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding: 0 5px 0 0;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 25%;
}

label::before {
  content: '\a0'attr(for)
}

b::after {
  content: 'null';
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked+b::after {
  content: attr(data-val)
}

.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 70px !important;
}
```

```html
<input type='checkbox' value='1'>
<input type='checkbox' value='true'>
<input type='checkbox' value='on'>
<input type='checkbox' value='z0' checked>
<input type='checkbox' value='1' checked>
<input type='checkbox' value='89m' checked>
<input type='checkbox' value='1'>
<input type='checkbox' value='cajun' checked>
<input type='checkbox' value='00'>
<input type='checkbox' value='v' checked>
<input type='checkbox' value='1'>
<input type='checkbox' value='A' checked>






<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```